# Order Channel Custom Field Options

Tags: custom-fields, channel-fields

I know, still asking newbie questions.

Maybe it is because I am running version 2.3.1, but it's not working for me.

I have a custom field options and I am trying to sort the checkboxes.

I have tried the following:

1) In the products template

```
{product_sizes markup="ul" orderby="product_sizes" sort="asc"}
```

2) In the Channel Fields> Edit Field> Field Options, I have literally ordered the options manually. They have to come up in order, right? Nope

Let me know what I am missing or is this a known issue?

Thanks in advance

Update with example:

```
<ul>
<li>32 oz, 32 servings</li>
<li>4 oz, 4 servings</li>
<li>16 oz, 16 servings</li>
</ul>
```

I would like it to be:

```
<ul>
<li>4 oz, 4 servings</li>
<li>16 oz, 16 servings</li>
<li>32 oz, 32 servings</li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried:

```
{product_sizes markup="ul" orderby="field_list_items" sort="asc"}
```

Should I change the database type for field_list_items from "text" to something else. I have read in other postings, that it cannot sort unless you change the type to INT, but how would I have a list of checkboxes, if it is type INT?

Comment: what type of custom field is this? (what's the fieldtype?)

Comment: They are Checkboxes - Channel Fields> Group Name (Products)> Field Label (Sizes)> Field Options

Comment: Let me clarify something, even though it is set as checkboxes for the backend, the selections made display as a bullet point list to the end user. That is the list that I would like to sort - what the end user views

Comment: the documentation does not seem to offer sort options. you can see the docs here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#checkbox-fields I did a test output in a site that I have in v2.5.3 (that's as old as I could test) and the fields output exactly as entered. If yours are not, and you've reordered them in the field definition, perhaps you need to a) clear template caches and/or b) re-save an entry to see if that changes anything.

Comment: I will give it shot when I return to work tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't work - I placed everything in numeric order with the numbers to the far left. 1 oz., 2 oz, etc... and it still comes out with 32 oz over 4 oz, maybe because 4 follows three? How can it not recognize 32 is greater than 4? And my 4 oz comes before 32 oz, WTx?

Comment: I apologize, it did work - after I changed some copy & re-submitted the entry. The sizes/servings show up in the order which they were entered. How do I mark your comment as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation does not seem to offer sort options. you can see the docs here: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#checkbox-fields

I did a test output in a site that I have in v2.5.3 (that's as old as I could test) and the fields output exactly as entered. If yours are not, and you've reordered them in the field definition, perhaps you need to a) clear template caches and/or b) re-save an entry to see if that changes anything.

**CONFIRMED**: Re-saving the entry will display the items in the proper order.